# List<Info> where Info has Last and First properties map to Dictionary<Last,List<First>>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

If I have a class of type

```
class Info
{
    public Info(string first, string last) { this.First = first; this.Last = last; }
    string First { get; private set; }
    string Last { get; private set; }
}
```

And a List for example:

```
var list = new List<Info>();
list.Add(new Info("jon", "doe");
list.Add(new Info("jane", "doe");
list.Add(new Info("bason", "borne");
list.Add(new Info("billy", "nomates");
```

And I want to map in to a sorted list of last name, with a list of firstnames, i.e. `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` where the key is the Last name property, and list is the list of First name properties.

In the example above I would like to get `{ "doe" => { "jon", "jane" }, "borne" => { "jason" }, "nomates" => { "billy" } }`.

Is it possible to do this neatly with Linq and if so how would I go about this?

Comment: You mention that you want it sorted, however your example is not sorted. A dictionary is an unordered collection.

Comment: Well spotted - I don't need any sorting, only grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) to get this done:

First, make your properties in your class public, then use this code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> names = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Last)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.First).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically prefer using an `ILookup<,>` for this sort of data. You can construct it like this:

```
list.ToLookup(e => e.Last, e => e.First);
```

While it technically isn't a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` like you asked for, it will still do most of the things you probably would have wanted to do.

```
var firstNamesByLastName = list.ToLookup(e => e.Last, e => e.First);
foreach(var firstName in firstNamesByLastName["bourne"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstName); // outputs "jason"
}
```

Note that you cannot change the `ILookup` object. So you can't add new names after it has been constructed. But the fact that you're looking to construct it with LINQ tells me you're almost certainly not intending to do that.

The other main semantic difference is that an `ILookup` will return an empty set if you query it for something that doesn't exist in it. Again, that's typically the behavior I'd prefer in cases like this.

```
// if this used a dictionary, we'd get an exception.
foreach(var firstName in firstNamesByLastName["unborne"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstName); // outputs "jason"
}
```

Comment: The only caveat is that lookups are not mutable.